# Query to move image between routes

Tags: javascript, image, next.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18ukf.png)
I am just trying to take an image input file from the user, then take it in to another route to display it there, so I am using query to achieve this.

Problem:
But for some reason the image is not displaying in that route, and I am not facing any kind of error.

So can anyone figure out what is the problem in what I am doing?
And if there is another method that can be used to achieve the same result that I want(pass image between routes)

Route code that contain image :

```
router.push(`/?image=${URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile)}`);
```

the selectedFile variable value is an object that came from this : event.target.File[0]

Route where I want to display image in :

```
  const [fileList, setFiles] = useState();
  const { image } = router.query || {};

  useEffect(() => {
    if (image) {
      handleFileUpload(image);
    }
  }, [image]);

  const handleFileUpload = (image) => {
    setFiles(<img src={image} alt="Story" />)
  };
```

I tried many things and many complex ways from using fetch to save the image in local storage, but nothing is working as expected and leads for the same result, no error, nothing displayed, so I think there may be a problem in the logic or fundamentals of the code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your folder structure? To tell whether you are using the app or the pages router.

Comment: I am using the app router, I added a screenshot for my folder structure anyway.

Comment: That's what I needed to know, thanks. I posted an answer, check it out and let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router, to get query parameters, there is a dedicated hook, called [`useSearchParams()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params):

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
```

```
const searchParams = useSearchParams()
const image = searchParams.get('image')
```